# GStreamer 1.4.4, Android Studio 1.3.2 and OS X Yosemite not working

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-ndk, gstreamer, java-gstreamer

I am trying to run up-to-date 'GStreamer 1.0' tutorials (http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/tree/gst-sdk/tutorials).

I have already installed GStreamer 1.4.4 for OS X (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/1.4.4/), and I am already using successfully the Android NDK.

But when I try to build any of the applications from the tutorials I get the next error:

> Error:(20, 33) error: package org.freedesktop.gstreamer does not exist

This is happening because it is not resolving this import statement:

> import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GStreamer;

I have read that this is because while building, it should make a new folder with GStreamer files, but that's not happening and I have no idea why.

My NDK version is r10e, my Gradle version is 2.2.1 and its plugin is 1.3.0. I am using on gradle.properties the instruction:

> android.useDeprecatedNdk=true

I have also set a path variable to the GStreamer SDK, on AndroidStudio -> Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment->Path Variables:

> GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID = /Volumes/HDD/Gstreamer/gst-sdk-debug-arm
>   GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID = /Volumes/HDD/Gstreamer/gst-sdk-debug-arm

Comment: After asking on the mailing list of gstreamer developers I am trying to solve it. If someone needs any hints I am updating this project on git as long as I have new clues to have it running:
https://github.com/danimarfil/android-tutorial-1

Comment: Does your project it github run, or is that your investigation in progress?

Comment: Actually it is my investigation in progress, but some people on the gstreamer mailing list have tried it and it worked for them. I have to say I have not found any solution so I have moved to ubuntu where at least I can easily install source gstreamer plugins. I have not tried the Android part there though.
FYI the readme file on gitub explains what I have changed from the original tutorial source code.

Comment: I have switched to Ubuntu as well. Send me an email, I am making progress. brian at surround dot io.